# Run python script each time mac wakes from sleep

Tags: python

I have a python file that I want to run every time the mac comes out of its sleep.
I have turned the .py file into an dmg file and placed into login items section of the mac this is in settings -> users -> login items.
My problem is that this seems to only run the DMG file when i fully logout of the the mac. I always just click the sleep option on the mac. Is there a way to run the python script each time the computer wakes up from a sleep?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps try making it into a shell script (so make a shell script that runs your python script) and then place that into it on startup.

Comment: Thanks. Its like inception, a script within a script. Il have to do a bit of research into shell scripts as im a bit new to it. So you mean in the shell script try and detect when the laptop has awoken from sleep mode and then activate the python script when that has been confirmed?

Comment: you could also compile it with pyinstaller and run it as app.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that might help: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-automate-your-python-scripts-on-mac-and-windows-459388c9cc94

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kitchen800 you can try making a shell script that runs your python program, or like another suggestion, use pyinstaller/py2app to make it into a executable application.  Putting the python program itself in the Open at login will simply open the python script, not run it.

##### Method 1: Make it a shell script

1. Make a file called `runpyscript.sh` (the file name doesn't matter, but keep the .sh)
2. Open the file with a text editor/IDE and write in it

```sh
python3 path/to/file.py
```

3. Save the file and navigate to your terminal
4. Run the command `chmod +x path/to/runpyscript.sh`
5. You can also get rid of the `.sh` at the end of the file to make it executable by double-clicking
6. Add this shell script to "Open at login".
   Now, when you login, it should (hopefully work and) open this shell script in terminal and run your python program.

##### Method 2: Make it an application with pyinstaller

1. Navigate to terminal
2. Put this in: `pip install pyinstaller` (if you haven't installed pyinstaller already)
3. Now put this in: `pyinstaller path/to/file --onefile <other options go here>`
   For more on the options, you can go to this link: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html
4. Now, you should have a .app file.  Navigate to your finder, press CMD+SHIFT+H, and go to the folder called `dist`.  There, you should find a `file_name_here.app` and you can put it in Open at login.

#### Method 3: Make it an application with py2app

1. Navigate to terminal
2. In the command prompt, put `pip install py2app`
3. Next, write `cd path/to/file`.
4. Now, you can generate a `setup.py` file for your python application.  In the command prompt, write `py2applet --make-setup file_name_here.py`
5. Once you have that done, you can do `python3 setup.py py2app -A` to construct the app in alias mode.  In the same directory, go to the folder called `dist` in Finder and open it.  You should find a `.app` file in it.  If anything goes wrong while opening the `.app` file, then configure `setup.py` and run `rm -rf build dist` and the above `setup.py` command again until it works.
6. Then, go back to terminal and write `python3 setup.py py2app` to build the final version of the app.
7. Once you're done, put it in Open at login.

Comment: No problem!  I hope everything works out well for you.